# How to reverse irreversible function in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion, inverse

How to reverse formula

$y(x)=x (\frac{1}{sin \frac{\pi x}{2}})^\alpha$

i.e. express it as

$x = x(y)$

in Mathematica?

I did this way

```
Clear[α, x, y]
Solve[y == x (1/Sin[Pi x/2])^α, x]
```

and it answered

```
During evaluation of In[39]:= Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

Out[40]= Solve[y == x Csc[(π x)/2]^α, x]
```

How to know, what prevent equation from solvation?

I have plotted formula for some values

```
Plot[Table[
  x (1/Sin[Pi x/2])^α, {α, {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}}], {x, 
  0, 1}]
```

and found nothing criminal in my expected domain

[image]

I have tried to add domain to the formula, but it didn't gave me answer anyway

```
Solve[y == x (1/Sin[Pi x/2])^α, x, 
 x >= 0 && x <= 1 && α >= -1 && α <= 1]

During evaluation of In[41]:= Solve::bdomv: Warning: x>=0&&x<=1&&α>=-1&&α<=1 is not a valid domain specification. Mathematica is assuming it is a variable to eliminate. >>

During evaluation of In[41]:= Solve::ivar: x>=0&&x<=1&&α>=-1&&α<=1 is not a valid variable. >>

Out[41]= Solve[y == x Csc[(π x)/2]^α, x, 
 x >= 0 && x <= 1 && α >= -1 && α <= 1]
```

How to set conditions correctly?

How to force to give computable result like as series?

**UPDATE**

Using `InverseFunction` I wrote:

```
MyFun2[x_, α_] := x*(1/Sin[Pi x/2])^α
MyFunInverse2 = InverseFunction[MyFun2, 1, 2]
```

which gave apparently good result:

```
Plot[Table[MyFunInverse2[y, α], {α, -1, 1, 0.25}], {y, 
  0, 1}]
```

[image]

but trying to produce computable expression failed:

```
Series[MyFunInverse2[y, α], {y, 0, 5}]

Out[73]= SeriesData[y, 0, {
InverseFunction[MyFun2, 1, 2][0, α], 
Derivative[1, 0][
InverseFunction[MyFun2, 1, 2]][0, α], 
  Rational[1, 2] Derivative[2, 0][
InverseFunction[MyFun2, 1, 2]][0, α], 
  Rational[1, 6] Derivative[3, 0][
InverseFunction[MyFun2, 1, 2]][0, α], 
  Rational[1, 24] Derivative[4, 0][
InverseFunction[MyFun2, 1, 2]][0, α], 
  Rational[1, 120] Derivative[5, 0][
InverseFunction[MyFun2, 1, 2]][0, α]}, 0, 6, 1]
```

**UPDATE 2**

I need to port function to C-like programming language, so final result should consist of "computable" operations. Is it possible?

How does Mathematica itself plots the result? Does just perform optimization algorithm inside? Is it really impossible to do otherwise, for example do with multivariate series?

**UPDATE 3**

If I take 3 terms of a series

```
Fwd[x_, \[Alpha]_] := x (1/Sin[Pi x/2])^\[Alpha]
In[115]:= Normal[Series[Fwd[x, \[Alpha]], {x, 0, 3}]]
Fwd1 = Function[{x, \[Alpha]}, %]
```

I see that result is quite applicable for me

[image]

nevertheless I can't reverse this (now much simpler) formula with neither `Solve`, `InverseFunction` and `InverseSeries`.

Isn't it really possible to get some short numeric series with 2-3-4 terms in the case???

Comment: Some (perhaps it's better to say most) expressions cannot be inverted analytically no matter how smooth they are. You can define a numerical inverse using InverseFunction if all parameters are known.

Comment: "Invert" is a better term than "reverse" here.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries so how to invert with `InverseFunction` having that $\alpha$ is an argument?

Comment: If all you need is a power series for the inverse function, you can calculate the power series for $x(y)$ and then use `InverseSeries` to find the power series for $y(x)$.  Note that $\alpha$ has to be an explicit rational number for this to work, though.

Comment: What range of $\alpha$ are you expecting?

Comment: @2012rcampion $[-1, +1]$

Answer (score 5):

If all you're interested in is the inverse power series, then don't calculate the `InverseFunction`;  instead, use the `InverseSeries` function:

```
fseries[α_] := Series[x (1/Sin[Pi x/2])^α, {x, 0, 5}]
Table[InverseSeries[fseries[α], y], {α, -1, 1, 1/2}]
```

[image]

Note that $\alpha$ has to be a rational number for this to work.  In particular, if you replace the `1/2` with `0.5` in the `Table` command above, it doesn't work:

```
fseries[α_] := Series[x (1/Sin[Pi x/2])^α, {x, 0, 5}]
Table[InverseSeries[fseries[α], y], {α, -1, 1, 0.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: So, how to solve for variable alpha?

Comment: InverseSeries[fseries[1], y] gives a correct result under v10.2, but under 11.3 I get strange result: ComposeSeries[SeriesData[
 SeriesDump`z$65839, 0, {1, 0, Rational[-7, 480] Pi^2}, 1, 5, 1]...

Answer (score 5):

You can get very close to the solution in three iterations of [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method):

```
f[x_, a_] := x/Sin[Pi/2 x]^a

fInvNewton[y_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, iter_: 3] :=
 Nest[# - (f[#, a] - y)/Derivative[1, 0][f][#, a] &, 
  If[y > 2/Pi, y, ((Pi/2)^a y)^(1/(1 - a))], iter]
```

Example:

```
Plot[Evaluate@{fInvNewton[y, 0.5, 3], 
   InverseFunction[f, 1, 2][y, 0.5]}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
LogPlot[Evaluate@
  Abs[fInvNewton[y, 0.5, 3] - InverseFunction[f, 1, 2][y, 0.5]], {y, 
  0, 1}]
```

[image]

Here's some pseudocode for the method:

```python
def fInverseNewton(y, a):
  # choose initial value
  if y > math.pi/2
    x = y
  else:
    x = ((math.pi/2)**a * y)**(1/(1-a))
  # three iterations of netwton's method
  for i in range(3):
    p = math.pi/2*x
    c = math.cos(p)
    s = math.sin(p)
    x = (a*x*p*c - y*s**(a+1)) / (a*p*c - s)
  return x
```